# Encoding issue when retrieving blob from SQL Server with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, encoding, c#-3.0

I've noticed a peculiarity when trying to store 2003 MS word documents within a SQL Server blob (`nvarchar(max)`) field and then retrieve them using Entity Framework (EF1) to then convert them back into a file (which is then attached to a email).

**Basic Code:**

1) I insert the document into the database using the openrowset:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Attachment]([id],[Blob])     
   SELECT 1, (SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk 'path_to_attachment\abc123.doc', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB)
```

2) I then retrieve the file from the database using EF1 (simplified for brevity - bypassing repo etc):

```
var attachment = (from a in ctx.Attachment where a.id == 1 select a).FirstOrDefault()
var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(attachment.Blob);
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var fileName = "abc123.doc";
var fileToAttach = new Attachment(stream, fileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

**Problem:**

This works, but I noticed some discrepancies with the file after pushing the file through this process, some minor formatting issues etc.

After doing some deeper digging (using VBinDiff) - it looks like some of the Unicode chars are being converted to FDFF

```
00DC > FDFF
```

original:

`00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 DC 00 00 00 00 00 00`

converted:

`00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  FD FF 00 00 00 00 00 00`

other example are:

```
BED9 > FDFF
CFD9 > FDFF
```

which looks to be the last in the range from here:
http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFB50.pdf

**Questions**

1) Am I doing something silly, or is EF doing something funky when returning the string object `attachment.Blob` - before I then try and convert it back to the byte array?

2) Is there a better way to retrieve the exact bytes out of the blob field while still using entity framework? (or should I use a stored procedure, or SqlDataReader instead - which I really don't want to do, in order not to convolute my data access paths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mitch's answer helped point out the failing in my code. For some reason (force of habit I think) I'd set the Blob field to be `nvarchar(max)` when, as pointed out by Mitch, `SINGLE_BLOB` saves the file information as a `varbinary(max)` which is actually what I wanted within the application anyway (See question point 2).

**Solution:**

1. Convert the database field from `nvarchar(max)` to `varbinary(max)`
2. Update the Entity Framework model
3. Change the blob field inside the EF model from `string` to binary`

And finally, change this

```
var attachment = (from a in ctx.Attachment where a.id == 1 select a).FirstOrDefault()
var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(attachment.Blob);
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var fileName = "abc123.doc";
var fileToAttach = new Attachment(stream, fileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

To this:

```
var attachment = (from a in ctx.Attachment where a.id == 1 select a).FirstOrDefault()
var stream = new MemoryStream(attachment.Blob);
var fileName = "abc123.doc";
var fileToAttach = new Attachment(stream, fileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Importing using [`SINGLE_BLOB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) returns the contents of a file as a single-row, single-column rowset of type `varbinary(max)`.

Rather than `SINGLE_BLOB`, I would suggest using `SINGLE_NCLOB` which reads a file as `nvarchar(max)`.

Unicode files must be read with the `SINGLE_NCLOB` option shown here:

```
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'path_to_attachment\abc123.doc', SINGLE_NCLOB) AS BLOB
```

Ref.: [Using OPENROWSET to read large files into SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1643)

**Update** (in response to comment): If the files are not unicode (as you tried) then when you retrieve them you should not use Unicode encoding to get the bytes:

```
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(attachment.Blob);
```

Comment: @Mitch-Wheat: If I try and change the parameter to `SINGLE_NCLOB` I get the error message: `SINGLE_NCLOB requires a UNICODE (widechar) input file. The file specified is not Unicode.` - Thanks very much for your reply btw.